# Determine the density function for coefficients of equation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Both roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ of a square equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ can take any value from $-1$ to $1$  with equal probability . Determine the probability densities for coefficients $a$ and $b$.

I think I should use the properties of Vieta's theorem then $x_1+x_2=-a$ and $x_1\cdot x_2=b$.

And I don't know how to solve it further

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "both roots ... can take any value from $-1$ to $1$ with equal probability?  Do you mean that the pair $(x_1, x_2)$ has uniform distribution on $[-1,1]^2$?

Comment: A continuous random variable always takes "any value with equal probability", namely $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that is exactly what I meant

Comment: Do not repost your question; edit your posts to draw attention.

Comment: @amd actually it isn't

Comment: That’s an automatic comment generated because I flagged this question as a duplicate of your previous one. As @StubbornAtom wrote, don’t repost your unanswered questions, especially not verbatim and after only a few hours.